# Difference between V|X| and V(X)

Tags: statistics

What's the difference between E(X) and E|X| & V(X) and V|X| ?

If I have V(X)= Theta^2 then what would be V|X|??

As far as I know  they are absolute values and make sure the series wouldn't tends to infinite....I.e they would be convergent.
But what if I have to determine some values of V|X| and E|X| when V(X) & E(X) are given??

Comment: $E|X|$ is horrible notation, but I would take it to be $E(|X|)$, not usually the same as $E(X)$.

Comment: Doesn’t theta^2 guarantee that it is positive already

Comment: @XcoderX Sure, variance is guaranteed to be positive, but it is also the case, assuming Lord Shark is correct in his assumption above, that the variance of $|X|$ is smaller than the variance of $X$ (the variance of $|X|$ is _not_ the same as the absolute value of the variance). Take, for an extreme example, the random variable given by $-1$ with $0.5$ probability and $1$ with $0.5$ probability. $X$ has variance $1$ while $|X|$ has variance $0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$V(|X|)$ and $E(|X|)$ are not determined by $V(X)$ and $E(X)$.  You can  compute them using the density or probability mass function of $X$.  Thus if $X$ has density $f$, $$E(|X|) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty |x| f(x)\; dx$$ and $$V(|X|) = E(|X|^2) - E(|X|)^2 = \int_{-\infty}^\infty |x|^2 f(x)\; dx - E(|X|)^2$$  Since $|X|^2 = X^2$ you can also say $$V(|X|) = V(X) + E(X)^2 - E(|X|)^2$$